# rails won't execute for newly created app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, bundler

I'm struggling to get going with rails, so apologies for being a n00b. I've installed and uninstalled Ruby and all of my gems several times now and am still having problems getting rails to launch. If I do...

```
$ rails new sample_app
...
$ cd sample_app
...
$ bundle install
...
$ rails s
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
$ gem install rake -v 10.5.0
Successfully installed rake-10.5.0
Parsing documentation for rake-10.5.0
Installing ri documentation for rake-10.5.0
Done installing documentation for rake after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$ rails s
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
$ rails --version
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I do `gem list` I see rake 10.5 is installed. I'm running Ruby 2.3.0 that I installed using rbenv. Running `bundle install` or `bundle update` as it indicates doesn't help. Suggestions?

Comment: try bundle exec rails s

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error

Comment: looks like similar issue to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826795/rails-not-finding-rake-10-5-0

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, but that doesn't seem to help unless the problem is that my version of ruby is too new

Comment: mine ruby version is 2.2.2

Comment: I would try to 1) delete gemfile.lock file, 2) run gem pristine --all  3) bundle exec bundle install, 4) bundle exec rails s.

Comment: You can also try `$ gem env home` - this outputs the directory where your gems are installed. Searching for the version of `rake` you have installed here (if any) should help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that error before, sometimes it needs to put

**gem 'rake'** to Gemfile, and run **bundle install**.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install rake
```

Comment: This may fix the immediate problem, but has the potential to cause shenanigans down the line if another project uses a different version of rake. [Rbenv's Github page](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) mentions that you shouldn't need `sudo` - assuming OP can get it working :)

Comment: @PatS use brew install instead of sudo apt-get install